# Calculate ratio between lengths/scale

Tags: lengths, scale, arithmetic

I would like to calculate the the ratio between two lengths in order to automatically get the scale for a map included using the mercatormap package. For instance, I want the map to show 1km in the horizontal direction and be `\textwidth` wide, this means that the scale argument I have to provide would be something like `100000cm / \textwidth`.

I found this solution:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\Gscale@div\tmp {100cm}{\textwidth}

{\textbackslash}textwidth = \the\textwidth

100cm / {\textbackslash}textwidth = \tmp

\Gscale@div\tmp {100000cm}{\textwidth}       % Causes: ! Dimension too large. <to be read again> [...] 
                                             % I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.

100000cm / {\textbackslash}textwidth = \tmp  

\end{document}
```

[image]

which apparently does not work for large dimensions. Given that `1pt` is about `28.4cm` the first ratio is calculated correctly, the second one on the other hand raises the error on the comment above. Got the same error using `\pgfmathparse` as well.

Is there a way to get around this "about 19 feet" limitation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `xfp` and `\fpeval`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

\edef\tmp{\fpeval{100cm/\textwidth}}

100cm = \the\dimexpr100cm\relax

\verb|\textwidth| = \the\textwidth

\tmp

\end{document}
```

Depending on your use case, you may be able to even avoid `\tmp`.

[image]

With `bc` I get

```
bc 1.06
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'.
2845.27559/345
8.24717562318840579710
```

so the results agree to the eighth decimal place, which is more than enough for TeX.

Comment: This works perfectly! And yes, it is way more precise than it needs to be! :) Thank you very much!